# Permutations with probability

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Question is we want to create a 3 digit number from the following numbers {0,1,3,5,7,8,9}

What is the probability that a  number contains no digit 5 and contains 2 or more identical digits

I can’t figure out the numerator,
I know the denominator should 7^3

Comment: To be clear... you say "*three digit number*"  Do you count $007$ as a three-digit number or a one-digit number?  Recall that $007$ is equal to $7$

Comment: As for the numerator... imagine if you will that your available digits were originally $\{0,1,3,7,8,9\}$ without the five.  Now, with *this* set of digits, answer the question of "2 or more identical digits."  Recall that the opposite of this is "*all distinct digits*".

Comment: Ahh I see so it would be just (6^3)-6P3/7^3

Comment: If you write `a-b/c` that is interpreted as `a - (b/c)` not as `(a-b)/c`.  Be more careful with how you write things.  Also, you never did respond to the question about what you call a "three digit number" and if 007 counts

Comment: Yh it would be counted as three digits I guess. The question doesn’t have any remarks so I assume yes

Comment: I meant (6^3-6P3)/7^3